# CallMethodAction on Enter KeyPress

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, attachedbehaviors

I have an attached behavior that uses the `CallMethodAction` behavior to call a method when the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is pressed. The `TextBox` XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="AddCategoryTextBox"
         Width="180"
         Text="{Binding Path=NewCategoryName,
                        Mode=TwoWay}"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=AddCategoryVisible,
                                     Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},
                                     Mode=TwoWay}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:KeyBehavior Key="Enter">
            <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="AddCategory" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </behaviors:KeyBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

I know the method is being called, because it also changes the `AddCategoryVisible` to `false`, which effectively hides the `TextBox`. Here is the `AddCategory` method:

```
public void AddCategory()
{
    if (AddCategoryVisible)
    {
        // insert new category and set current invoice id
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NewCategoryName))
        {
            var categoryId = InvoiceCategories.Count;

            var category = new InvoiceCategory
            {
                CategoryName = NewCategoryName,
                CategoryDescription = "",
                CategoryId = categoryId
            };
            _invoiceCategoryRepository.InsertAsync(category);

            InvoiceCategories.Add(category);
            CurrentInvoice.CategoryId = categoryId;
            NewCategoryName = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    AddCategoryVisible = !AddCategoryVisible;
}
```

The problem is that when I hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, the `TextBox` will disappear, but the new category is not always added. If I go back to add new category again, the entered text is there, and if I hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again, it is successful.

I have a `Button` which calls the exact same method when clicked, and it works 100% of the time. I'm not sure what would be the difference, is there something that I'm not seeing?

The method was originally `async` and the `InsertAsync()` call was `await`ed, but I took it out for the time being to see if that would make any difference. Unfortunately, the behavior is still not working properly from the `CallMethodAction`, but works fine from the button click. Here is the XAML for the `Button`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=AddCategoryCommand}"
        Content="+" />
```

And the `AddCategoryCommand` definition:

```
public DelegateCommand AddCategoryCommand => new DelegateCommand(AddCategory);
```

As you can see, the `Button` is just calling the same `AddCategory` method as the `TextBox`.

**EDIT**

I think it should also be noted that I have tried to set a breakpoint in the method to make sure everything is behaving correctly. With the breakpoint, the method executes correctly every time, so it seems to me to be some sort of timing issue, which is why I tried removing the `async` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Well. You can either use Template 10 or you can steal the KeyBehavior from it. I am the author of Template 10 and stealing code from it is perfectly fine.

> https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Behaviors/KeyBehavior.cs

Here's an example of how to use it:

> https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Templates%20(Project)/Minimal/Views/MainPage.xaml

```
<TextBox MinWidth="150" MinHeight="62"
                Header="Parameter to pass"
                Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <!--  enable submit on enter key  -->
        <Behaviors:KeyBehavior Key="Enter">
            <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GotoDetailsPage" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
        </Behaviors:KeyBehavior>
        <!--  focus on textbox when page loads  -->
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            <Behaviors:FocusAction />
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Best of luck.

Comment: That is indeed exactly where I had gotten the `KeyBehavior` from. I am halfway working on a WinRT project while gradually porting it over to a new Template 10 project. Maybe I will just leave the issue alone for now in the 8.1 app and keep my fingers crossed that it will work properly when I get to that point in the Universal app.